# A Spanish judge has jailed two key members of the Catalan independence movement. Have others been ever accused and convicted for sedition?

Tags: law, constitution, catalonia, spain, constitutional-monarchy

As of 16th October 2017, [A Spanish judge has jailed two key members of the Catalan independence movement](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41646142). As the BBC news reports:

> Jordi Sánchez and Jordi Cuixart, who lead prominent separatist groups, are being held without bail while they are under investigation for sedition.

Indeed, [Jordi Sánchez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordi_S%C3%A0nchez_i_Picanyol) and [Jordi Cuixart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordi_Cuixart) are respectively the leaders of  [Catalan National Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assemblea_Nacional_Catalana) (ANC) and [Òmnium Cultural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%92mnium_Cultural), the main organizations supporting the independence of Catalonia.

As the report says:

> They are being investigated over a protest on 20 September in which a crowd blocked Civil Guard officers inside a building in Barcelona, Catalonia's regional capital.

For this, the judge has decided to jail them immediately without a bail under the accusation of sedition: [Spanish prosecutor seeks sedition charges for leaders of Catalan protests](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/09/22/spanish-prosecutor-seeks-sedition-charges-leaders-catalan-protests/). In this news we can read *The crime carries a charge of up to 15 years in prison* and it describes the context of the accusation:

> At least 40,000 demonstrators descended on the Catalan department of economy as it was raided on Wednesday, blocking agents inside from leaving for up to nine hours until the judge who had ordered the operation made a midnight phone call to the head of the Catalan police.

Just for the sake of context: Human Rights Watch reported [Spain: Police Used Excessive Force in Catalonia](https://www.hrw.org/news/2017/10/12/spain-police-used-excessive-force-catalonia) a few days later.

I found some news (like [La sentencia del Supremo que esgrime la Fiscalía condenó por sedición el bloqueo de un desahucio](http://www.elmundo.es/espana/2017/09/24/59c7e48722601dfc068b4686.html), in Spanish) talking about a case in 1976 where some neighbours from Huesca were accused of this crime, but the sentence was later on reduced.

For this, I wonder: has anybody been found guilty of sedition since the Constitution of Spain was approved in 1978? What was the prison sentence for them?

Comment: Would rebellion count? Because from [the law](http://carris.wanadooadsl.net/leyes/leyesaccesodirecto/cp24.htm)(Spanish link), sedition is a lesser form of rebellion. In any case, from reading the law, the 15 year maximum time is appliable only to authorities and neither Jordi Sánchez and Jordi Cuixart count as "authorities"; the actual maximum they could face is 10 years.

Comment: @SJuan76 yes! Rebellion would also work. In fact, I thought _rebellion_ was less than _sedition_. In [¿Qué son los delitos de sedición y rebelión?](https://politica.elpais.com/politica/2017/09/20/actualidad/1505908751_228608.html) I see they mention these thresholds you commented, and also indicate that rebellion (sedition + violence) would imply up to 25 years.

Comment: *condenado* in this context would more typically be translated *convicted*.

Comment: IMO sedition sounds absurd to be an actual reason for conviction in a democratic country.

Comment: @Communisty agreed. Over 200K people demonstrated yesterday in Barcelona against the decision: [Catalonia: Protests after Spain detains separatists](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41655095). It is also worth explaining that the Civil Guard was not prevented from doing their job and these two people are shown in videos asking people to let the police leave the building.

Comment: @Communisty Sedition is just a form of interference with the police, the main difference being that sedition is done collectively (more than 30 people). And I do not know of any country (democratic or not) where interfering to or trying to stop police work is not punishable. At any rate, that people has not yet been convicted, they have been charged and have been denied bail (hint: if you are ever accused and have to go before a judge, avoid stating publicly that you do not acknowledge the judge's authority. It makes it seem as if you will keep doing whatever you have been charged with).

Comment: @SJuan76 the demonstrations did not try to stop police work, they gathered around the place they were _doing_ their work. By the way, I just [read](http://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/auto-sonroja_6_698240190.html) that supposedly the Audiencia Nacional is not competent to judge this case and, also, the charges used to put them in provisional prison have received many accusations for their bias and appear unsubstantial.

Comment: @fedorqui The demonstrations were illegal and prevented the police force to leave the building they were at, until more police forces were ushered it, and the accused organized the demonstrations and kept them going. Whether those facts are the basis for a sedition charge or a lesser one of resistence to authority is something that I am not very sure about(I certainly will be glad to see a more precise definition of the limit), but that is why it must be proven in trial (or, if not proven, proceed with their absolution). And competence issues should be resolved through appeals.

Comment: @SJuan76 how come do you say demonstrations on September 20 were illegal? Under what circumstances a gathering of people would be illegal? // Agreed regarding competence issues.

Comment: https://hayderecho.com/2012/10/03/el-derecho-de-reunion-y-manifestacion-resumido-para-juristas-y-no-juristas-ministros-del-interior-incluidos/; in short it was not a "gathering of people" but a rally, demonstration (it had a political intention) and as such it requires notification and can be rescinded if needed -and yes, a rally with the object of preventing police force would not have been allowed-. Not that it happens often (as proof, all of the manifestations that happen every day), most issues are mostly preventing the rally from going near some conflictive spot.

Comment: And of course, even non-political events that involve lots of people (say, music concerts, or even more regular events like football matchs that gather large crowds) must be notified and are subject to restrictions, mostly in order to ensure public safety (send police to regulate vehicle trafic, coordination for emergencies, define the maximum number of people who can safely attend, etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I've found is that some aerial controllers were accused of sedition during the massive [strike of 2014.](https://politica.elpais.com/politica/2017/10/05/sepa_usted/1507215430_835681.html) In the article is hinted that the accusation of sedition has been rarely been made in Spain since it's democratic, but it doesn't provide any more insight. I've been unable to find how many people have been accused of sedition, nor the resolution of the cases.

**ADDITION:** In both cases (aerial controllers and the rebellion of the attempted *coup d'êtat* of 1981), the accusation was based on militar laws, not the civil code. So far I've been unable to find a case of someone accused of sedition based on common penal code.

Comment: Was about to answer but you beat to me, I only want to add that if rebellion is included as a variation of sedition, then the most famous instance would be that of the people who took part [in the failed *coup d'état* of February 23, 1982](http://www.lavanguardia.com/hemeroteca/20170603/423093424397/23-f-golpes-de-estado-politica-espana-juicios.html) and who were found guilty of "military rebellion".

Comment: @SJuan76 that is a good one. Just a clarification: it was in 1981.